# How to catch mouse-over event on Dynamic or Tiled Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, identify, dynamic-layer

I need to fetch as IMAGE, the results of querying/filtering the data of a layer. 
So, I decided to use the dynamic service layer.

I can use the identify task to so as to show an infobox containing the information of a point. However it is slow and it could work only onclick.

The problem is that I MUST make popup-infoboxes play on MOUSE-OVER. 
THis makes the use of Identify task infeasible, since I would have to send  requests all the time, when the user moves his mouse over the map.

1) So, How could I get the info of the point that my mouse is currently over, when using DynamicServiceLayer?

2) Could I use any other type of layer, that brings the results as Images to achieve mouse over?

3) Is there any best practice for infoboxes and dynamic service  layers for better performance?

You can take a look at [these exaples using tileJSON](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/11/exploring-mapbox-stack-mbtiles-tilejson.html) . They are based on tileJson. Can't Arcgis do somethig like that ?

Answer (score 1):

in order to implement a 'mouseover' event listener, you would need a reference to an actual graphic (JSON describing the geometry and attributes of the feature of interest) within your client app.

Comment: Thank you @John Gravois . I know. I am currently investigating whether the use of leaflet (I think you are involved in it)  and GeoJSON would help. I have seen an implementation where wax and leaflet are used to do so. Here is a part of the code:

Comment: // add click & tooltip functionality
     var waxmap = wax.leaf.interaction()
      .map(map)
      .tilejson(tilejson)
      .on(wax.tooltip().animate(true).parent(map._container).events());

Comment: Hey @John Gravois Please take a look at this implemetations: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/11/exploring-mapbox-stack-mbtiles-tilejson.html . They are based on tileJson. Can't Arcgis do somethig like that ?

Comment: vector tiles are coming to the ArcGIS ecosystem, but they aren't baked yet.  https://www.mapbox.com/blog/vector-tile-adoption/

Comment: Haha unlucky :(